# Bootstrap right col right absolute aligned to page with no-padding

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

I'm trying to create a row with two cols. And right col should be right aligned to the page... I don't want use container-fluid... please help...

Thanks

[image]

Comment: Are you wrapping your row > col content in a container?

Comment: I just need one col aligned to right just like pic…

Comment: please post your code,

Answer (score 0):

As for now to align the one column to the right so that it takes up the whole screen, I would think that you would be better off with custom styling.

```
https://www.codeply.com/go/oPTBdCw1JV
```

It would be a lot easier to figure out this problem if you post an example code snippet with the picture.